# Firebase Database Query Returning Wrong Results

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android Studio application that queries a user and pull user information based on user login credentials (email). So I pass email from one activity (login) to another activity (profile). In ProfileActivity is where I query Firebase database, and I use the user email address to pull specific user information eg: full name, profession, address, etc.. This is the structure of my database:

```
user-registration-app
   users
      -Lu8jvjlDWKbgK1ibeku
         email: johndoe@gmail.com
         fullname: John Doe
         address: 1234 nw thistreet
         profession: developer
 -Lu8jvjlDWKbgK1ibeku
         email: janed@gmail.com
         fullname: Jane d
         address: 3444 nw thistreet
         profession: diver
```

So in profile activity, I'm creating a reference to "users" and then `orderbychild()`where email is equal johndoe@gmail.com, but is returning some weird address (memory address).

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child(USERS);
Log.v("EMAILADD", String.valueOf(userRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email)));
```

Do I need to do access the key id before I can access orderByChild("email")? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is returning some weird address (memory address)

That's the expected behavior since you are trying to log the String representation of a Firebase Query object.

```
userRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email)
```

Return an object of type [Firebase real-time database Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/query).

If you want to get the values that correspond with that query, you should save that query to a variable and use a listener, like in the following lines of code:

```
Query query = userRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String email = ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, email);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: what if email is unique... do I still have to loop through the dataset? is there a simpler way if I know is returning a single data

Comment: Yes, the `dataSnapshot` object contains a list of user objects. Even if there is only a single result, the `dataSnapshot` will contain a list of one result. No, there is not. This is the simplest one.